# Network related issues are not getting logged on sentry platform

Tags: javascript, next.js, sentry

I have integrated Sentry into one of my Next.JS application and I'm also able to see JavaScript related errors like reference or syntax error on Sentry platform.

Though sentry is not logging any network related errors on their platform. Got 403 Forbidden, 404 Not found and 500 internal server error on my network calls, but sentry did not reported any of those.

I have used the following steps for the setup:

1. Installed the SDK using this command `npm install --save @sentry/nextjs`
2. Used the wizard automate the initial steps using this command `npx @sentry/wizard -i nextjs`
3. Added all configurations from next.config.js to next.config.wizardcopy.js
4. Deleted next.config.wizardcopy.js and renamed next.config.wizardcopy.js to next.config.js

I have initialised Sentry both in my client and server file like this

```
Sentry.init({
  dsn: '***',
  integrations: [
    new CaptureConsole()
  ],
  tracesSampleRate: 1.0
});
```

I have used CaptureConsole method to capture all errors which are there on console and checked on sentry docs and different online available resources for network related errors but got no help.

Could anybody please help me on the same, what can I more use to get network related errors. In case, if it is not possible, let me know that as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am using reactjs, I added `new BrowserTracing()` as well. You can try this

```
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/react";
import { CaptureConsole } from "@sentry/integrations";
import { BrowserTracing } from "@sentry/tracing";

Sentry.init({
    dsn: "https://e44884be8781480fa50344a421e5aaba@o4504315282653184.ingest.sentry.io/4504315339210752",
    integrations: [
        new CaptureConsole(),
        new BrowserTracing()
    ],

    // Set tracesSampleRate to 1.0 to capture 100%
    // of transactions for performance monitoring.
    // We recommend adjusting this value in production
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I have used try catch statements on my code there while handling the xhr request and sentry does not log errors which are already handled (used try catch statements), one have to manually log errors on sentry using captureException method in that case